# Loop and sum array Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

does anyone know how to loop an array & sum it? So i have an array with 3 values like in the picture below

[image]

and this is my code

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use laravel collection [`sum()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sum) method instead of getting sum of array value in loop.

```
collect([1, 2, 3])->sum();
```

or use php [`array_sum()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) method

```
array_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```